# How should python convert tiff image to jpg format without having to save to harddrive?

Tags: python, heroku, jpeg, tiff

I'm trying to process some images and obtain numerical output. The skimage library only works with jpg format images. I only have tiff images on hand. Most converting functions work by loading a tiff image and saving it in jpg format. I do agree that the easiest way is

```
PIL.Image.open('pic.tiff').save('pic.jpg','jpeg')
```

I'm, on the other hand, trying to abstain from using hard drive for several reasons, but mainly due to the complexity file handling on heroku. Hence the question.

Comment: It looks like `skimage` can handle TIFF images, with the right plugin: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.io.html

Comment: What are the possible values for the plugin? I tried io.find_available_plugins() to search available ones ones. It returned matplotlib, simpleitk, imread, gtk, tifffile, gdal, pil, qt, imageio, fits. I would expect that tifffile would be able to decompress tiff images, but I received: "ValueError: cannot decompress ccittfax4"